# How to make GCP instance use PHP 7.2 instead of 7.0

Tags: php, apache, google-compute-engine

I created a LAMP stack instance on Google Cloud Platform, launched with PHP 7.0, I need Laravel installed so I installed PHP 7.2 from the SSH console (debian).
While using `php -v` it shows that the current installed version is 7.2 while the vm instance informations shows that it's still using 7.0 instead and also the Laravel script is not working because I suppose PHP 7.0 is still in use.

I already found ways on how to require using a different version on App Engine, but I need this for Compute Engine (LAMP stack on debian 9).

Thanks.

Comment: Have you followed all the steps to upgrade the VM from 7.0 to 7.2? If you have 7.2 already installed, you can follow [this guide to perform the upgrade](https://medium.com/andrewmmc-io/upgrade-php-version-to-7-2-from-7-0-c005a0926642)

Comment: Thank you, I found an important step which I didn't bear in mind.

Comment: Sure thing, glad to be of help. I will post this as an answer then so that it's easier to see by the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to upgrade PHP to 7.2 after installing it. You can follow the guide over [here](https://medium.com/andrewmmc-io/upgrade-php-version-to-7-2-from-7-0-c005a0926642) to find the steps needed to do this.

Hope you find this helpful.